# A new user of KairosDB get an exception on startup

Tags: kairosdb

While I'm trying to start up KairosDB I keep running into the exception in the below quote.

I'm sure *cassdrandhost config* is correct.

How to I fix it?

> [Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService-1]
>   ERROR [CassandraHostRetryService.java:219] - Downed Host retry failed
>   attempt to verify CassandraHost
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame
>   size (-2080374784)!   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1101)
>   ~[cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1089)
>   ~[cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService.verifyConnection(CassandraHostRetryService.java:214)
>   [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]    at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService.access$100(CassandraHostRetryService.java:24)
>   [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]    at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService$1.run(CassandraHostRetryService.java:75)
>   [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
>   10:39:37.604 [main] WARN  [HConnectionManager.java:303] - Exception: 
>   me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HectorTransportException:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame
>   size (-2080374784)!   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:195)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:185)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:104)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:253)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.describeKeyspace(AbstractCluster.java:199)
>   [hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]    at
>   org.kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.CassandraDatastore.(CassandraDatastore.java:135)
>   [kairosdb-1.1.1-1.jar:1.1.1-1.20151207194217]     at
>   org.kairosdb.datastore.cassandra.CassandraDatastore$$FastClassByGuice$$ccf4844f.newInstance()
>   [guice-3.0.jar:1.1.1-1.20151207194217]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:60)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) [guice-3.0.jar:na]
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) [guice-3.0.jar:na]
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) [guice-3.0.jar:na]
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) [guice-3.0.jar:na]
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
>   [guice-3.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.kairosdb.core.scheduler.KairosDBScheduler.start(KairosDBScheduler.java:68)
>   [kairosdb-1.1.1-1.jar:1.1.1-1.20151207194217]     at
>   org.kairosdb.core.Main.startServices(Main.java:451)
>   [kairosdb-1.1.1-1.jar:1.1.1-1.20151207194217]     at
>   org.kairosdb.core.Main.main(Main.java:304)
>   [kairosdb-1.1.1-1.jar:1.1.1-1.20151207194217] Caused by:
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame
>   size (-2080374784)!   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:133)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
>   ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1241)
>   ~[cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_keyspace(Cassandra.java:1228)
>   ~[cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar:1.2.5]   at
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster$4.execute(AbstractCluster.java:190)
>   ~[hector-core-1.1-4.jar:na]   ... 46 common frames omitted

Comment: I is a capital.  Got rid of 'I'm a beginner" to focus on the question and the large stack trace. Broke Question in to three separate lines too show that their are 3 ideas. Reworded the title to better summerize the problem.